# "for each" loop in reverse

Tags: actionscript-3, foreach, reverse

Is it possible to have "for each" loop in reverse?
Or the only way to do it is like

```
for(var i:int = maxnumber; i>0; i--)
{
  //something
}
```

Comment: [reverse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#reverse%28%29) the array you want to iterate first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse array:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#reverse()

And have "for each" loop. After loop you can reverse again.

Comment: The thing is it won't give any benefits. Ordinary for or while(i-- > 0) will be faster.

Comment: Mentioned faster (faster execution) ways neither harder, nor dirtier.. but faster, which is the ONLY thing developers want from loops.

Comment: Today machines has enaught power for this simple job. It is unnecessary to save every megahertz

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll need to use an ordinary `for` loop.